# Making div element wide enough for a text string

Tags: css

Is it possible to make the width of the absolutely positioned div big enough to contain the text, but not bigger? 
I tried inline-block, but it doesn't seem to work, because once I set the position:absolute the div will take the max width of the parent element.

Could you suggest what changes I can make to the child element, so that it float in the center of the parent div and has smallest width possible but fits the text string inside.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmmrfmk0/

```
<div class='grand-parent'>
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
        long long long string
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.grand-parent {
    position: absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
.parent {
    position:relative;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    width:500px;
    height:100px;


}

.child {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color: #ccccc0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:15px;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Use `white-space:nowrap` and remove top, left, right, bottom 0 values and the position the element where you want it. In this case, dead center of the parent div.

```css
.grand-parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #ccccc0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='grand-parent'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      long long long string
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='grand-parent'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      long long long string ong long long string
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly indeed! I'm checking all browsers right now, but it looks like a nice trick(still a trick). Do you know any performance implications/other drawbacks by using transform in this scenario?

Comment: Performance...no issues AFAIK. This is basic CSS3 so you might have a little trouble in old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your .child class includes left:0 and right:0

This will force the div to be as wide as it's parent, inline-block will not over-ride this.

Remove right:0 from .child and it should work as you want

Comment: But it will no longer be in the center... right now if I add width: 100px to the child, it floats at the center position

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmmrfmk0/3/). If you display the parent as table-cell and put vertical-align as middle then you can position vertically.

```
.grand-parent {
   position: absolute;
   width:500px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:red;
}
.parent {
   position:relative;

   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;

   width:500px;
   height:100px;
   text-align: center;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;

}

.child {
   background-color: #ccccc0;
   border: 1px solid black;
   height:15px;
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;


}
```